# Django file-size chaos (in finder and compressed folder)

Tags: python, django, macos, unix

I went to zip up a Django project to send it when I noticed that the project was over 600 MB.

I think the sqlite3 database file was over 450mb, so I went through some steps to reset it and deleted the profiler app that was generating all that data.

However, when I inspect he root folder I still see around a ~400 mb file size for the whole project.

Here is my finder output for `ls -lha` (which seems pretty ridiculous in itself?)

App:

```
drwxr-xr-x  14 funglr-dan  staff   448B Feb 13 11:03 django_app
```

What?? 448 bytes? Clearly not right.
Inside the App:

```
drwxr-xr-x  13 funglr-dan  staff   416B Feb 13 11:04 .git
-rw-r--r--   1 funglr-dan  staff   500B Feb 13 11:03 .gitignore
drwxr-xr-x   3 funglr-dan  staff    96B Jan 15 20:49 .vscode
drwxr-xr-x  26 funglr-dan  staff   832B Feb  7 16:30 bin
-rw-r--r--   1 funglr-dan  staff    97B Jan 15 20:49 date-test.py
drwxr-xr-x   3 funglr-dan  staff    96B Feb  7 16:30 include
drwxr-xr-x   3 funglr-dan  staff    96B Jan 11 18:44 lib
-rw-r--r--   1 funglr-dan  staff    60B Feb 13 10:26 pip-selfcheck.json
drwxr-xr-x   3 funglr-dan  staff    96B Jan 30 18:31 selenium
drwxr-xr-x   9 funglr-dan  staff   288B Feb 13 10:56 webapp
```

Yet, when I inspect that very same django_app folder in the finder, the finder reports 506.2 MB

facepalm..

Comment: I'm curious now if that runs

Comment: yeah, the app is working as expected

Comment: That is strange, have you tried rebooting and seeing if that corrects the issue?

Comment: That does seem to have worked.. Must have just gotten caught up on something. What's frustrating is all of these giant compressed files I made

Comment: Sometimes the best debugger is a nice, long break.